# push and replacing the json array in an existing array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

my json data:

```
     {
  "items": [
    {
      "propertyId": 9,
      "hp_builders_id": 1,
      "property_name": "Godrej Avenues",
      "properties": [
        {
          "UnitName": "1 BHK+1T",
          "property_size": "629 ",
          "bedrooms": 1,
          "unit_type_name": "1 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 2704071,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 45
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "1 BHK+1T",
          "property_size": "706 ",
          "bedrooms": 1,
          "unit_type_name": "1 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 3035094,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 46
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1042 ",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 4479558,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 47
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1045 ",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 4492455,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 48
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1050 ",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 4513950,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 49
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1089 ",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 4681611,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 50
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1521 ",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 6538779,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 51
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1523 ",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 6547377,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 52
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1525 ",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 6555975,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 53
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1526 ",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 6560274,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 54
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "builders": {
        "builders_id": 1,
        "builders_name": "Godrej",
        "builders_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2016-07-27T00:00:00.000Z",
        "update_date": "2016-08-17T09:41:21.000Z"
      },
      "propertyId": 1,
      "hp_builders_id": 1,
      "property_name": "Godrej Woodsman Estate",
      "property_latitude": "13.0544261",
      "property_longitude": "77.5918467",
      "property_status": 1,
      "created_date": "2016-08-01T10:17:34.000Z",
      "update_date": "2016-09-07T03:39:45.000Z",
      "properties": [
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1400",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 11400200,
          "price_per_sqft": "8143",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 81
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1835",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 16999440,
          "price_per_sqft": "9264",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 84
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1729",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 16000166,
          "price_per_sqft": "9254",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 85
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1460",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 18501120,
          "price_per_sqft": "12672",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 86
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1325",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 13501750,
          "price_per_sqft": "10190",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 87
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1460",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 16000140,
          "price_per_sqft": "10959",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 88
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1800",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 21000600,
          "price_per_sqft": "11667",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 89
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
          "property_size": "1750",
          "bedrooms": 3,
          "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 15001000,
          "price_per_sqft": "8572",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 90
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "4 BHK+4T",
          "property_size": "2302",
          "bedrooms": 4,
          "unit_type_name": "4 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 29999664,
          "price_per_sqft": "13032",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 91
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+2T",
          "property_size": "1459",
          "bedrooms": 2,
          "unit_type_name": "2 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 13999105,
          "price_per_sqft": "9595",
          "hp_property_id": 1,
          "unit_price_id": 92
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but i want to change the response of that json as like this :

```
    {
  "items": [
    {
      "propertyId": 9,
      "hp_builders_id": 1,
      "property_name": "Godrej Avenues",
      "property_start_date": "0000-00-00",
      "property_completion_date": "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "property_launch_date": "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "total_launched_apartments": 420,
      "total_property_area": 5,
      "property_description": "Godrej Properties presents Godrej Avenues at Yelahanka, Bengaluru with 1, 2, 2.5 and 3 BHK homes that keep you happy every day. Located on the Yelahanka-Doddaballapur Main Road, the 10 majestic towers spread over 5.3 Acres with a Sky Lounge set at 45.72 metre you experience the high life right at your doorstep. At Godrej Avenues, come home to a world of happiness every day.",
      "property_latitude": "13.1495363",
      "property_longitude": "77.5610062",
      "property_status": 1,
      "created_date": "2016-09-06T02:49:09.000Z",
      "update_date": "2016-09-06T03:22:56.000Z",
      "properties": [

      {"UnitName": "1bhk"
           data:[
          {
          "UnitName": "1 BHK+1T",
          "property_size": "629 ",
          "bedrooms": 1,
          "unit_type_name": "1 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 2704071,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 45
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "1 BHK+1T",
          "property_size": "706 ",
          "bedrooms": 1,
          "unit_type_name": "1 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 3035094,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 46
        }]
    },
 {"UnitName": "2bhk"
           data:[
          {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+1T",
          "property_size": "629 ",
          "bedrooms": 1,
          "unit_type_name": "1 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 2704071,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 45
        },
        {
          "UnitName": "2 BHK+1T",
          "property_size": "706 ",
          "bedrooms": 1,
          "unit_type_name": "1 BHK",
          "unit_type_status": 1,
          "UnitPrice": 3035094,
          "price_per_sqft": "4299",
          "hp_property_id": 9,
          "unit_price_id": 46
        }]
    }

      ]
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

so based on bedrooms,i want to separate that elements like (1bhk as 1bhk+1t, 1bhk+2t  and 2bhk as 2bhk+1t, 2bhk+2t).so based on condition how to change the code

my code :

```
for(var property in clubproperty){
       console.log(clubproperty[property]);

        if(clubproperty[property].bedrooms=='1'){

       console.log(clubproperty[property].UnitName);
            items=clubproperty[property];
            console.log(items);
            a.properties[groupProp].unitname="1 BHK";

            properties:[{
                unitname:'3bhk',
                items:[]

            }]

        }


    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I see that there has been no code provided for this - you have only provided data. Could you share the code that you have right now? We can look at it and help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this approach:

```
var source = {"items": [] };

source.items.map(function(item){
    var result =
       item.properties.reduce(function(p, c){           
           p[c.unit_type_name] = p[c.unit_type_name] || [];

           p[c.unit_type_name].push(c);

           return p;
       }, {});

   return Object.keys(result).reduce(function(p, c){
       return { UnitName : c, data: result[c] }
   }, {});
 });
```

Comment: thanq for u answer.i am getting but i want to set key for unitname {unitname:"1bhk"items:[1bhk+1t]} .almost everything is ok